# React routing - id params in the URL is undefined when I pass it with history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I managed to to use history.push in an onClick as I want to pass the user id to a Profile page component but the uuid params in the URL is undefined and I don't know why. I'm really stuck at this part.

I also want to pass all the other props which I get from the Random User Generator API as I'm doing in CardList to be able to build the profile page.

Would definitely appreciate anyone’s help.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Card = ({ history, firstName, lastName, email, uuid, image, city, country }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="tc bg-washed-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 dim bw2 shadow-5 pointer">
        <img src={image} alt="userImage" onClick={() => history.push(`/profilepage/${uuid}`)} />
        <h2>{`${firstName} ${lastName}`}</h2>
        <p> {email} </p>
        <div>
          <span>{`${city}, ${country}`}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Card);
```

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const ProfilePage = ({ uuid }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="f1">Profile Page: {uuid}</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

and this is the Routing in App.js

```
render() {
    const { users, isPending } = this.props;
    if (isPending) {
      return <h1 className="tc"> Loading... </h1>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="tc">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/homepage" render={() => <CardList users={users} />} />
            <Route path="/profilepage/:uuid" component={ProfilePage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";

const CardList = ({ users }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="f1"> IOTA Users </h1>
      {users.map((user) => {
        return (
          <Card
            key={user.login.uuid}
            image={user.picture.large}
            firstName={user.name.first}
            lastName={user.name.last}
            email={user.email}
            city={user.location.city}
            country={user.location.country}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ProfilePage` component you can get the `uuid` like below ways

- Approach-1: In this approach you either need to spread all the other `props` which will be sent from parent or else need to use `...rest` param to capture all the other props which you don't want to spread.

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const ProfilePage = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="f1">Profile Page: {match.params.uuid}</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

- Approach-2: This way you can access other `props` also

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const ProfilePage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="f1">Profile Page: {props.match.params.uuid}</h1>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProfilePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Look like you don't send uuid as props. Can you check CardList component?

There is undefined because it's not actually send uuid data as props. You should fetch it from `this.props.match.params.uuid`

Can you also check is there exist your id in url? If so my method should work.

And from react-router-dom version 5 you can use their hook like `useParams`. So, you can make your code base more clear

Comment: my id shows in the url as undefined yes. I don't quite understand how can i fetch it with ```this.props.match.params.uuid```. can you elaborate?